# Obtain a series expansion of $a^2(q)a^2(q^4)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, theta-functions

Let $a(q)$ denote the Borwein function $$a(q)=\sum_{m,n=-\infty}^\infty q^{n^2+nm+m^2}.$$
In this [research paper](https://people.math.carleton.ca/%7Eaalaca/pubs/aa2006-1.pdf) the author has obtained the series expansion for $a(q)a(q^4)$. I want the series expansion of $a^2(q)a^2(q^4)$. I have squared the series and obtained an expression, but that series seems to be very long and not expressible in powers of $q$. But I want a series representation in powers of $q$.

This is in reference to my M.Sc project and I need some guidance at the moment. Kindly help me out or at least point me in the right direction. At present I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: You already have a power series in $q$: $a^2(q)a^2(q^4)$. Expanding it you'll get a complicated expression for the coefficients. Then you can look at those indexed in lmfdb.org, your modular form will be a linear combination of the $f(dz)$ for $f$ of same weight and level $| \frac{l}d$, you will be able to identify from the first few coefficients, if you are lucky there will be no complicated cusp forms.

Comment: @reuns I am not sure what you mean.  Could you kindly explain ?

Comment: $a(q)$ is a power series, so is $a(q^4)$, and the product of power series is a power series.

Comment: @reuns Is there any way to obtain the series expression without the use of modular forms ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "series seems to be very long and not expressible in powers of q"? Please show us your work and explain what you mean by this statement because the square of a power series in q is **obviously** a power series in q. Also, where exactly in the linked PDF is the series you refer to located?

Comment: In the article, I found that equation (1.12) denotes the q^n coefficient of $a(q^l)a(q^m)$ by $N(l,m;n)$. Then Theorem 15 expresses $N(1,4;n)$ in terms of $\sigma$ arithmetic function. The article does not mention $a^2(q^l)a^2(q^m)$. Only just the case of $a^2(q)$.

Comment: One can get an approximate count by the circle method - you're counting solutions to the the equation $ n_1^2 + n_1 m_1 + m_1^2 + n_2^2 + n_2m_2 + m_2^2 + 4 n_3^2 + 3n_3 m_3 + 4m_3^2 + 4 n_4^2 + 4 n_4 m_4 +4 m_4^2 = n$. But for an exact answer, modular forms may be the best approach. Is there a particular reason you want to avoid modular forms theory?

Answer (score 3):

The same group of authors work out the answer to your question in theorem 2 of [this paper](https://people.math.carleton.ca/~williams/papers/pdf/289.pdf), so you can simply cite their result.

As mentioned in the comments, the answer gets more complicated because it doesn't just involve the divisor function, but also the fourier coefficients of newforms of weight 4 on $\Gamma_0(6)$ and $\Gamma_0(12)$. You can check a proof of the same result in the language of (quasi-)modular forms in the article [Evaluation of convolution sums and some remarks on cusp forms of weight 4 and level 12](http://www.niser.ac.in/~brundaban.sahu/W_12-revised.pdf) by B. Ramakrishnan and B. Sahu.